# Looping over JavaScript object and adding string to end if not the last item

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, foreach

```
{
field_country: ["England", "Netherlands", "India", "Italy"],
field_continent: ["Europe"],
field_group: ["Building", "People", "Landscape"
}
```

I want to loop over each item and return the key and the array together with ending 'OR' for example:
field_country: "England" OR field_country: "Netherlands"
The last item should not end with 'OR' in the loop. I am not sure what the best process is for this using vanilla JS. So far my code is as follows:

```
Object.keys(facets).forEach(function(facetKey) {
  if (facets[facetKey].length > 1) {
    facetResults = facets[facetKey];
    for (var i = 0; i < facetResults.length; i ++) {
      if (i == 1) {
        filter = "'" + facetKey + "'" + ":'" + facetResults[i] + " OR";
        return filter;
      } else {
        filter = "'" + facetKey + "'" + ":'" + facetResults[i];
      }
   }
} else {
  filter = "'" + facetKey + "'" + ": " + facets[facetKey] + "'";
  return filter;
}
});
```

I would be very grateful for any assistance.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: append the **or** at the beginning of the string when index > 0 instead of adding it at the end when index > -1

Comment: The classic Fence Post problem. The basic algorithm is to start at your first post (element at index 0 in this case) and post-pend your fence (the `" OR "`) up until the second to last element, then add your last post. 

As others have pointed out, the array join function does this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional expression `if (i == 1)` would only trigger on the second iteration of the loop since `i` will only equal `1` one time.

Try something like:

```
if (i < (facetResults.length - 1)) {
    // only add OR if this isn't the last element of the array
    filter = "'" + facetKey + "'" + ":'" + facetResults[i] + " OR";
    return filter;
}
```

Here's your updated code:

```
Object.keys(facets).forEach(function(facetKey) {
  if (facets[facetKey].length > 1) {
    facetResults = facets[facetKey];
    for (var i = 0; i < facetResults.length; i ++) {
      if (i < (facetResults.length - 1)) {
        filter = "'" + facetKey + "'" + ":'" + facetResults[i] + " OR";
        return filter;
      } else {
        filter = "'" + facetKey + "'" + ":'" + facetResults[i];
      }
   }
} else {
  filter = "'" + facetKey + "'" + ": " + facets[facetKey] + "'";
  return filter;
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if you would like to get the final result in the form of an object:

```js
const data = { field_country: ["England", "Netherlands", "India", "Italy"], field_continent: ["Europe"], field_group: ["Building", "People", "Landscape"] }

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
  r[k] = v.join(' OR ')
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

It is somewhat unclear what is the final format you need to result in but that should help you to get the idea. If ES6 is not an option you can convert this to:

```
const result = Object.entries(data).reduce(function(r, [k, v]) {
   r[k] = v.join(' OR ')
   return r
}, {})
```

So there are is no `arrow function` etc.

The idea is to get the arrays into the arrays of strings and use the Array.join to do the "replacement" for you via `join(' OR ')`

Comment: Instead of `v.toString().replace(/,/g, ' OR ')` you can use join: `v.join(' OR ')`.

Comment: Sure. Good call. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the idea. In your code you are appending " or " at the end of your strings starting at index 0. I suggest you append it at the the beginning starting at index 1.

```
var somewords = ["ORANGE", "GREEN", "BLUE", "WHITE" ];
var retval = somewords[0];
for(var i = 1; i< somewords.length; i++)
  {
    retval += " or " + somewords[i];
  }
console.log(retval);

//result is: ORANGE or GREEN or BLUE or WHITE
```

Comment: Just set `retval = some words[0];`, start at index 1, and do just your else branch.

Comment: @DrewReese, it took me a moment to understand but you are so right! Changed it and I'll remember this comment!

Comment: Brilliant one !